# ¿Por que no me ejecuta la funcion ajax() al hacer click en el enlace?

Tags: javascript, ajax

El problema es el siguiente:
El primer script funciona, es decir, me muestra el contenido del fichero que le paso donde debe de mostrarlo, pero no quiero eso, lo que quiero es lo que explicare en el script de mas abajo.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function ajax(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('formulario').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
    }

    req.open('GET', 'agregarUsuario.php', true);
    req.send();     
}   

ajax();
```

Al pulsar en el enlace con id #agregarUsuario es cuando quiero que me muestre la funcion, y no lo hace, alguien sabria por que?

pd: he probado a hacer click en el enlace y pasarle la funcion hide() y la ejecuta, pero la ajax() no.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ajax(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('formulario').innerHTML = req.responseText;
            }
        }

        req.open('GET', 'agregarUsuario.php', true);
        req.send();     
    }   

     $("#agregarUsuario").click(function(event) {
         ajax();
     });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes la biblioteca JQuery implementada?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema puede ser porque no estas cerrando el ultimo paréntesis para el evento click.

Intenta agregandolo:

```
    $("#agregarUsuario").click(function(event) {
      ajax();
    });  // Este es el último paréntesis que falta
```

Comment: si lo estoy cerrando, lo que pasa que al copiar el texto y y ponerlo bien, lo he borrado sin querer aqui, pero esta cerrado

Comment: Podrías subir tu html por favor, para detallarlo mejor.

Comment: no me deja subir el html, no se por que....

Answer (score 0):

Incluye este link en tu head del HTML, que es la librería JQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Debes inicializar el Estado de preparación de jQuery para que jQuery funcione, metiendo el Código en

```
$(function(){ 

});
```

Código de ejemplo tuyo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    function ajax(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('formulario').innerHTML = req.responseText;
            }
        }

        req.open('GET', 'agregarUsuario.php', true);
        req.send();     
    }   

     $("#agregarUsuario").click(function(event) {
         ajax();
     });
});
</script>
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="formulario"></div>
  <button id="agregarUsuario" type="button">Click</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      function ajax() {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('formulario').innerHTML = req.responseText;
          }
        }

        req.open('GET', 'agregarUsuario.php', true);
        req.send();
      }

      $("#agregarUsuario").click(function(event) {
        ajax();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tampoco funciona asi

Answer (score 0):

no estás bindeando al evento click, sino usando el click directamente. Como no veo el resto del html, entiendo que antes has cargado jquery y demás. Debes asegurarte además que se ha cargado el document y entonces bindear el evento click a tu enlace

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

function callToAjax() {
  alert('hello Ajax');
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#agregadorAjax").on("click", callToAjax);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello Ajax</p>
  <button id="agregadorAjax">Call</button>
</div>
```

Te paso un snippet para que pruebes el binding del evento y veas una idea muy genérica.
Hay otros modos de bindear el evento. Lo podrías hacer en el html mediante onclick, usando bind con javascript etc...

Comment: si el jquery esta cargado, de hecho en el script de clickar el enlace con esa etiqueta, si le paso la funcion hide() la ejecuta y oculta el elemento de la etiqueta, pero si le paso la funcion ajax() no la ejecutar, es muy raro y por las vueltas que le doy al codigo y cambio cosas, no funciona, sin embargo si saco la funcion fuera del click funciona, pero no quiero eso :(

Comment: probaste lo que adjunto? la diferencia radica en el .on("click" ... si ejecutas el codesnippet que adjunto verás que sale el alert al hacer click

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solucion, resulta que si le tenia puesto el href asi, pues no lo cargaba. Tan solo cargando el documento js de mis funciones y añadiendole el onclick al enlace ha bastado.

No valido

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="" id="agregarUsuario" onclick="agregarUsuario()"
```

valido

```
<a class="dropdown-item" id="agregarUsuario" onclick="agregarUsuario()"
```